# path to svg not working with img tag in Gatsby

Tags: image, svg, gatsby

I am trying to use svg images that I can pass as props (I will be using an array of svg images).  I am using gatsby-plugin-react-svg which allows me to import the svg and use it as a component.  This works but I can't pass the svg images as props or reference them in an array this way.  While looking for a solution I have seen many suggestions to import the svg and then use it as the src in an img tag.  This would work perfectly for me but it doesn't work when I try it.  Do I need a different plugin to use svg images this way?

This works (which also means that my path is correct):

```
import CurrentSelected from "../assets/markers/current_selected.svg"

<Layout>
  <CurrentSelected />
</Layout>
```

These don't work (but is what I need to use):

```
import CurrentSelected from "../assets/markers/current_selected.svg"

<Layout>
  <img src={CurrentSelected} />
</Layout>
```

OR

```
<Layout>
  <img src={require("../assets/markers/current_selected.svg")} />
</Layout>
```

While looking for a solution, I have seen this suggested as a solution but it doesn't work in my project.  Can anyone help me to render my images this way (or any other way that's not using the svg as a component)?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this a little while ago, I just wanted to follow up on my own question in case anyone else has this same issue.

The issue was that gatsby-plugin-react-svg converts the SVG files into React components so the path was returning a React component, not an SVG file.  To fix it, I had to remove the gatsby-plugin-react-svg and after that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> This works (which also means that my path is correct):

Not necessarily , the path when importing from the SVG is inferred by webpack sourcing from the plugin (`gatsby-plugin-react-svg`) and may differ when [importing assets directly](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/recipes/working-with-images/). Check the relativity of your paths:

```
import CurrentSelected from "./src/assets/markers/current_selected.svg"

<Layout>
  <img src={CurrentSelected} />
</Layout>
```